# from 15 minutes interval to hourly interval counts

Tags: sql, excel

am using excel sheet to display data from sql with this query

```
SELECT itable.Timestamp, itable.Time,
Sum(itable.CallsOffered)AS CallsOffered, Sum(itable.CallsAnswered)AS CallsAnswered, Sum(itable.CallsAnsweredAftThreshold)AS CallsAnsweredAftThreshold,
sum(CallsAnsweredDelay)AS CallsAnsweredDelay 
FROM tablename itable
WHERE 
(itable.Timestamp>=?) AND (itable.Timestamp<=?) AND 
(itable.Application in ('1','2','3','4'))
GROUP BY itable.Timestamp, itable.Time
ORDER BY itable.Timestamp, itable.Time
```

and i get a data with an interval of 15 minutes like this :

```
Timestamp   Time    CallsOffered    CallsAnswered   CallsAnsweredAftThreshold   CallsAnsweredDelay
6/1/2014 0:00   00:00   0   1   1   52
6/1/2014 0:15   00:15   3   1   1   23
6/1/2014 0:30   00:30   3   3   2   89
6/1/2014 0:45   00:45   0   0   0   0
6/1/2014 1:00   01:00   0   0   0   0
6/1/2014 1:15   01:15   4   1   1   12
6/1/2014 1:30   01:30   1   1   1   39
6/1/2014 1:45   01:45   0   0   0   0
6/1/2014 2:00   02:00   2   1   0   7
6/1/2014 2:15   02:15   1   1   1   80
6/1/2014 2:30   02:30   3   2   2   75
6/1/2014 2:45   02:45   0   0   0   0
6/1/2014 3:00   03:00   0   0   0   0
```

and i want to convert the interval from being 15 minutes to hourly interval 
like this

```
2014-07-01 00:00:00.000
2014-07-01 01:00:00.000
2014-07-01 02:00:00.000
2014-07-01 03:00:00.000
2014-07-01 04:00:00.000
2014-07-01 05:00:00.000
2014-07-01 06:00:00.000
2014-07-01 07:00:00.000
2014-07-01 08:00:00.000
2014-07-01 09:00:00.000
2014-07-01 10:00:00.000
2014-07-01 11:00:00.000
2014-07-01 12:00:00.000
2014-07-01 13:00:00.000
2014-07-01 14:00:00.000
```

the query i came up with is :

```
select 
  timestamp = DATEADD(hour,datediff(hour,0,app.Timestamp),0),
  Sum(app.CallsOffered)AS CallsOffered,
  Sum(app.CallsAnswered)AS CallsAnswered,
  Sum(app.CallsAnsweredAftThreshold)AS CallsAnsweredAftThreshold,
  sum(CallsAnsweredDelay)AS CallsAnsweredDelay,
  max(MaxCallsAnsDelay) as MaxCallsAnsDelay , 
  max(app.MaxCallsAbandonedDelay)as MaxCallsAbandonedDelay
from tablename app
where Timestamp >='2014-7-1' AND timestamp<='2014-7-2' and 

(app.Application in (
'1',
'2',
'3',
'4')
group by DATEADD(hour,datediff(hour,0,Timestamp),0)
order by Timestamp;
```

i get the result i want when i run in in Microsoft Sql server Managment studio 
but it gives me a long error when i try running the same query in Microsoft Query in excel the error is like i cant start with timestamp 
and that its giving me error for DATEADD ,DATEDIFF 
so is there something i should change in my query or anything i can do to get an hourly count interval instead of 15 minutes count interval as ive shown 
and thank you in advance

Comment: Try remove `timestamp = ` and replace with, at the and of the line, `as a_column_name`. Once that is done also change the order by for the new column heading. `timestamp` as a column heading might be an issue (don't know if it is or isn't) [Could you provide the exact error message? ]

Comment: [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSQRY32.EXT]

Comment: [SQLCODE:<-12>:<A term expected,beginning with one of the following :identifier ,constant, aggregate,$$,:,(,+,-,%ALPHAUP,%EXACT,%EXACT,%MVR,%SQLSTRING,%SQLUPPER,%STRING, or%UPPER>]

Comment: [Location:<Prepare>] [%msg:<Aterm expected,beginning with either of :identifier ,constant, aggregate,$$,:,(,+,-,%ALPHAUP,%EXACT,%EXACT,%MVR,%SQLSTRING,%SQLUPPER,%STRING, or%UPPER^select timestamp>]

Comment: i couldnt copy so i wrote it down in three seperate comments to be clear